# What is the underlying code for TableA.create(TableB.all.map(&:attributes))?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, copy

For example, if I use rename method in mongo ruby driver, I can check the [code here](https://github.com/karlseguin/mongo-ruby-driver/commit/cda8ce94ae6aabe29bbaf485b4fe9b4485c61c9f#diff-1)

What exactly is happening when I am using map(&:attributes)?
I think this means tags.map(&:attributes.to_proc).join(' '), but I am not sure why I am getting "undefined method `each_pair' for Arrayxxxxx" error with this command:

```
TableA.create(TableB.all.map(&:attributes))
```

Any insight will be appreciated

Comment: Not a duplicate, but thanks for the pointers, I will check all these links out. I am just trying to understand why 'each_pair'..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map returns an array of whatever is returned by the method call.

so

```
TableB.all.map(&:attributes)
```

is basically an array of

```
[TableB.all[0].attributes,TableB.all[1].attributes,TableB.all[2].attributes,...]
```

Do you want something like

```
TableB.all.map(&:attributes).each do |attr|
  TableA.create(attr)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Olives! You helped me to solve a very hard problem!